# How to stop editing a JCombobox in a JTable when changing tab in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane

I need to add a JCombobox which is having an editable textfield in a JTable. This JTable is present in a tab of JTabbedPane.

The issue is, whenever I keep combobox text editor in edit mode and change the tab, the combobox textbox is still in edit state only. I want it to be disabled when we are changing the tab.

I have tried adding requestfocus to tabbedpane but of no use. Please suggest any way to make this textfield of combobox inactive when the tab is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ChangeListener` to your tabbed pane to capture tab change events. From that listener, you can delegate to a method that stops the JTable editor from editing.

```
ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
    int previousIndex = 0;

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
      JTabbedPane tbPane = (JTabbedPane) changeEvent.getSource();
      stopTableEditor(tbPane.getComponentAt(previousIndex));
      previousIndex = tbPane.getSelectedIndex();
    }

    private void stopTableEditor(Component component) {
        JTable table = ... // retrieve table instance from component
        if(table.isEditing())
           table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this again..As I'm new to this I have not known this.